# TypeScript TS2322: Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to compose some classes using ES2015 module syntax with TypeScript. Each class implements an interface in a `.d.ts` file.

Here is a MWE of the problem.

In a `.d.ts` file I have:

```
interface IBar {
  foo: IFoo;
  // ...
}

interface IFoo {
  someFunction(): void;
  // ...
}
```

My export is:

```
// file: foo.ts
export default class Foo implements IFoo {
  someFunction(): void {} 
  // ... 
}
// no errors yet.
```

And my import is:

```
import Foo from "./foo";

export class Bar implements IBar {
   foo: IFoo = Foo;
}
```

The error here is:

```
error TS2322: Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'.
Property 'someFunction' is missing in type 'typeof Foo'.
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you say `foo: IFoo = Foo;` you are assigning the *class* `Foo` to `IFoo`. However the interface `IFoo` is implemented by *instances* of that class. You need to do :

```
foo: IFoo = new Foo;
```

Comment: Rookie mistake, thought I was doing something wrong with TypeScript, when it was an issue with the actual JS... Thanks.

Comment: What if I want to say the variable will not be an instantiated class, but instead a class that will implement the interface but be instantiated at a later point? Is this possible?